# Unix : ssh is working through command line but not through script

Tags: sh

Below command is working through command line :

```
expect -c 'spawn ssh username@Host ; expect "assword:" ; send "<password>\r" ; interact;'
```

Below is not working if I include in a script

```
while read server_from_file
do
    expect -c 'spawn ssh username@${server_from_file}; expect "assword:" ; send "<password>\r" ; interact;'
done < serverlist.conf
```

Please also let me know how could we run certain commands using the above script

Comment: In the second case, stdin to `expect` is coming from the file `serverlist.conf`  That is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`expect` inherits stdin from its environment.  In the first case, `expect` uses the script's stdin as its stdin.  In the second case, `expect` inherits stdin from the enclosing while loop, so it will be reading from the file.  One typical solution would be to use a different fd for the loop.  eg:

```
while read server_from_file <&3  
do
    expect -c 'spawn ssh username@${server_from_file}; expect "assword:" ; send "<password>\r" ; interact;'
done <3 serverlist.conf
```

(Note, some shells provide -u, and there are other ways to do this, but this should get you pointed in the right direction.)

Comment: Any idea how could I pass some commands after doing ssh to the remote server ?